# stored ref object in reducer, does not have offsetTop property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a dynamic survey form generator. I saved all question's ref objects into an array in the reducer. I want to access refs from all other pages to scroll user to specific question. my problem is that stored objects, doesn't have an offsetTop to use for scroll.

there is no difference between using ref's callback or not.

```
class Question extends React.Component<QuestionProps,{}>{
    myRef:any;
    constructor(props:QuestionProps){
        super(props);
       ...
        this.myRef = React.createRef();   // Create a ref object 
    }
...
render(){
        const {question,activeQuestionId} = this.props;
        const active = activeQuestionId === question.id;
        return <Row ref={this.myRef} className="QuestionBox" style={{opacity:active?1:0.2}} onClick={this.handleQuestionClick}>
```

in the reducer i have:

```
case SET_QUESTION_ACTIVE:
        console.log(state);
        const currentRef = state.refs.filter(c=> c.questionId === action.payload.questionId);
        if (currentRef.length > 0) {
          const currentQuestionRef = currentRef[0].ref;
          window.scrollTo(0, currentQuestionRef.current.offsetTop);
        }
```

currentQuestionRef.current is correct object that we could see in the console.
but currentQuestionRef.current.offsetTop is undefined!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ref` with react components like `<div>`, `<input/>` and  ... like the following example:

```
    render(){
     return(
    <div ref={this.myRef}>
     //code comes here
    <div/>
 );
}
```

or you can send the `ref` as `prop` into another component.